# MVC Layered Project Structure With Oauth 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth

We are having a new web project using C# / MVC 5, Entity Framework code first and Oauth 2 for authentication.

Here is how the solution is structured:

```
Project.DAL (Class Library): Contains EF DbContext and Repository classes
Project.BLL (Class Library): Contains business logic classes / Models
Project.Web (MVC Project)
```

But when we were building the project with individual authentication, the oauth part has automatically been created in Project.Web, should we move OAuth into BLL layer? Or what should we do to make the structure properly?

Thanks  for your time

Answer (score 0):

**AsyncOAuth**

Portable Client Library and HttpClient based OAuth library, including all platform(for PCL as .NET 4.0, .NET 4.5, Silverlight4, Silverlight5, Windows Phone 7.5, Windows Phone 8.0, Windows Store Apps).

Install

using with NuGet, AsyncOAuth

```
PM> Install-Package AsyncOAuth
```